# Can't open or create file in Photoshop CC 2017 x32

Tags: adobe-photoshop

CC 2017, Win 10. This problem occurred suddenly. I didn't get any errors. Just after trying to open file or create new one nothing happened. All `.psd` files I tried to open aren't broken.

I have enough RAM (16GB and there is enough free RAM for PS). I've also installed different versions from 2014 to 2017, x32 and x64, but it hasn't helped.

I see the following warnings and errors: https://pastebin.com/ssXe6Jhm

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Are there dialog boxes hidden behind windows on your screen? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: I don't get error messages, no dialog boxes. I didn't checked error logs yet, in process...

Comment: I checked this [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/launch-log-files-location-ccm.html) but I've not found any logs in that folders

Comment: Also check the System an Application Event logs for any interesting errors.

Comment: @DavidPostill I checked Event Viewer and there are not any errors connected to PS neither System nor Application